# How can I adjust screen brightness on Toshiba C665-X5010?

Tags: 14.04, display, screen, brightness

I am using Toshiba C665-X5010 laptop having NVIDIA GeForce 315M GPU. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 recently and I couldn't adjust my screen brightness. Please help me.